# Does every Fano variety contain every abstract curve?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

It is a famous result of Mori that all Fano varieties (in characteristic $0$) contain rational curves. What if we replace rational curve with a specific curve of positive genus?

**Question.** Is it true that for any (smooth, projective, connected) curve $C$ and any (smooth, projective) Fano variety $X$ over an algebraically closed field (edit: $\dim X \geq 3$) there exists a morphism $f:C \to X$ such that $f$ is
[(0) nonconstant?]
(1) birational onto into image?
(2) a closed immersion?
(3) ... some other natural condition?

The answer to (0) is yes, because we can obtain such maps as compositions $C \to {\mathbb P}^1 \to X$.

However, I have no idea about the others. Is the answer known? If not, is it "almost certain" that it's positive? It seems that way, but there's still a shadow of doubt in my mind.

*Note.* The only scenario I think I can rule out is: the answer is known to be negative. Because I think that would give examples of Fano varieties which are not unirational, and this is still open afaik.

EIDT: solved by Jason Starr's comment below.

Comment: Doesn't (2) fail most of the time for $\mathbb{P}^2$, since most curves are not plane curves?

Comment: @Ari Shnidman: You are right, but I think the OP had in mind the case $\dim(X)\geq 3$.

Comment: In characteristic $0$ that is true, in fact it is true for all separably rationally connected varieties in every characteristic.  In positive characteristic it is open: we do not know whether all Fano manifolds are separably rationally connected in positive characteristic.

Comment: @Jason Starr: Thank you very much. In very few words, what's the technique? (Is it something like deforming some curve of arithmetic genus $g$ with rational components and somehow the deformation theory turns out right? If that's it, then my questions isn't that interesting.)

Comment: @Ari Shnidman : my bad, edited!

Comment: Yes, it is a deformation theory argument.  Every separably rationally connected variety contains a rational curve such that the restriction of the tangent bundle is ample.  If you now precompose that embedding of the rational curve by a sufficiently high degree morphism from $C$ to the rational curve, then the pullback of the tangent bundle to $C$ is a "very very ample" locally free sheaf.  Now you deform.

Comment: Got it, thank you!